# Bluetooth audio choppy playback

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, windows-10, bluetooth

I got a new laptop recently (HP Envy 17t). I'm using a bluetooth audio device (LG Soundbar) as playback device. Radio is Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265. During playback, the stream gets choppy on irregular intervals. In example, it can play for 5 minutes without any problems, but then it can start chopping so much that it's impossible to recognize the song. Or it can simply skip a beat every 30 secs or so. These problems don't occur when laptop speakers are used as a playback device. Also, I had no issues with my old Envy and LG Soundbar. I tried updating the drivers but it didn't help. I have an impression that when I'm disconnected from WiFi, the problem is not so drastic. But it might not be related.

It might, or might not be related, but latency is much higher than my old laptop:
[image: Latency]

There is no significant improvement when I disable the wireless device.. just a few green bars pop in, but most are still yellow.

Comment: That tool doesn't show correct values for Windows 8+. Use [LatencyMon](http://www.resplendence.com/latencymon) instead.

Comment: here's the pastebin : http://pastebin.com/a0KxNin2

Comment: Your NIC driver takes 16ms to make a DPC, which is very high. Do you have the latest version?

Comment: yup, that's the first thing I did, updated all the drivers

Comment: @spherical_dog looks much better with Wireless card disabled, using just cable: http://pastebin.com/mzn3KqFp .. is this simply crappy Intel drivers?

Comment: Try all of these drivers until you find the one that doesn't cause spikes. https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/83635/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7265

Comment: Those latencies are too high even with the NIC driver disabled. Some other device might be at fault here.

Comment: thing is windows 7/8 drivers won't work, tried them already :(